# Validating two date text boxes using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, validation

I have seen many ways to validate these dates, but I don't actually know which is the best way to validating the two text boxes.

Once I click on my submit button, the `onsubmit = check()` will check the dates if they are correct or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle validation in Javascript is with regular expressions.  Check out examples [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re4.shtml)

If you need to manipulate the date, i.e. if you want to convert it through code then you need to split the string up using the Split function and then combine it in the correct order again.  Check out example [here](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php).